# What does "Gem Powered" mean for powerups? And how do they carry over?

Tags: temple-run-2

When selecting a powerup (not ability) in Temple Run 2 you have the option of making it "Gem powered". For example, here is the Coin Bonus one:

[image: "Instant 50 coin bonus. 100 when Gem powered."]

It's easy enough to infer that this gives you 50 gems normally, and 100 when you spend a gem on it.

**However, what happens when you add one, two, three, or more gems?**

Here's what I tried. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gufXg.png) is what the screen looks like when you add one gem and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GuHO.png) is what happens when you add two. Adding more simply fills the bar without text changes. After powering with two gems, here is what happens [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrsau.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q11Bk.png) using the powerup in-game: even if I spent two gems, I only got 100 coins. [This spent *both* gems.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/src43.png)

**What is the point, if any, of upgrading past one gem? Is this specific to the Coin Bonus powerup?** Or is this just a glitch and it should be adding 50/100 coins per gem?

Comment: The description sounds like, "+50 coins when used.  If powered completely, give +100 instead."  So yeah.  That's strange.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem right. Each gem should give you a single, gem-powered coin bonus (+100 instead of +50). Are you sure you charged the meter with two gems? Because your image of one-gem charge looks like my zero charges, and your two-gem charge looks like mine when I add one. The charges I don't use carry over to later runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bear in mind that Temple Run 2 is a 'free to play' title - they make their money from people buying in-game items, so there are lots of ways to burn through coins and gems.

In this case you can 'gem-power' a power up so that the next time you use it you get more from the power. 1 gem gives you 1 boosted power up use, 2 gems gives you 2 and so on.

If you're going for a long score run you might cash in 5 gems so that you can use the boosted power 5 times.

To be honest, for the amount you get back it's a waste of gems.

Comment: So, if I spend five gems does it last five _games_ or five _uses_?

Comment: @JoeMasilotti 5 uses, which could all be in a single run. Should be easy to test...

Comment: @Keith not without losing 5 gems...

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that spending gems on power-ups **is not an investment**.

Gems spent on a power-up get consumed when you the power-up.  I would advise not spending any gems on these power-ups, instead save them for the 'save me' feature.

I learnt this the hard way :(

Comment: Yes, except the Gem Powerup that you unlock on Level 9.  Gems spent on the gem powerup will pay for themselves as quickly as you could fill up those bars with coins.

Comment: @WilliamC only 50% gain, but still something :P

Comment: FolksLord, it actually doubles the yield. The nominal thing is that, if you spend 4 gems, the next time you use the gem powerup, you get 6 gems. The original four gems are essentially returned, so you get 2 gems instead of the regular 1 per use. So basically, as long as you have this filled up, you get twice as many gems for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that spending multiple gems will allow it to work for multiple uses (spend 3 gems, and the first 3 uses of coins will give 100) but regardless of how many you spend in one game, all are lost after one game, but I haven't tested this yet.  I don't have the coin power-up yet, and it's hard to test with the others.

Answer (score 0):

I do have to say that the first powerup i filled completely. the green bar is compleley full, and it has never decreased. Do they stay maxed if you can fill the bar in one go? i havent really paied any attention to the fact that if i use it it decreases. i should check into that.

(i would like to add that i just tested this and they will stay in the green as long as you dont use the power up. so investing gems into an ability is a waste unless your trying to reach a goal of a distance or certian amount of points)